# batch file closes after specifying what I want to do

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to code something that creates a file with a password in it if the file does not exist and if it does exist I want it to ask you what the current password is in order to reset it, I am coding it all in batch

```
@echo off
:start
echo -create (create password. reset password)
echo -check (checks password if you need a reminder)
set /p FUNCTION= what would you like to do? 
goto %FUNCTION%

:create
cls
if exist "Password" (
    :check1
    cls
    set /p PASSWORD1= What is your password?
    for /f "Delims=" %%a in (Password) do (
        set TEXT=%%a
    )
    if %PASSWORD1%==%TEXT% goto correct
    echo this password is incorrect
    pause
    goto check1

    :correct
    echo This password is correct
    pause
    goto correct1
) else (
    set /p PASSWORD= type your password here! 
    echo %PASSWORD% > Password
    pause
    goto start
)

:check
cls
set /p PASSWORD1= What is your password?
for /f "Delims=" %%a in (Password) do (
    set TEXT=%%a
)
if %PASSWORD1%==%TEXT% goto correct
echo this password is incorrect
pause
goto check

:correct
echo This password is correct
pause
goto start

:correct1
set /p PASSWORD= type your password here! 
echo %PASSWORD% > Password
pause
goto start
```

Comment: You cannot use labels within a parenthesised block. You also need to take care if you're using `goto` with labels, if you're insistent upon using multiple duplicate label names. I have indented your code so you can properly see how it is currently running. I'll ask that you review it, and let us know if that is really how you have it currently, or whether you've modified your actual code, and made one or more typing errors in the above version.

Comment: this was copied and pasted from my actual code and I would like to have the fixed version along with what you fixed so I can learn from it edit-  I am not very experienced with batch what does parenthesised mean?

Comment: Even if you had provided us with a full explanation of what your code is supposed to do, in every possible scenario, _(which you clearly have not)_, this site isn't here to recode your script. We only help you to fix a specific issue, given all the information we need to reproduce it. I would therefore advise that you remove the labels from the parenthesised blocks, or recode in a way which doesn't rely upon them, _(one method may be to use `call`)_. Then if you still have an issue, edit your question to update your code, and provide all pertinent information.

Comment: You should also open up a Command Prompt window, type `choice /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and take a look at the usage information. Using `choice.exe` for known input options is more robust than trying to deal with anything which can be done at a `set /p` prompt.

Comment: Are you aware that `echo %PASSWORD% > Password` actually writes an additional space and your `for` loop re-reads the password *including* that space? Note that `"S3cret"` will never be equal to `"S3cret "`. Better use `(echo %PASSWORD%) > Password`